# Newbie at Python, i was trying to create a calculator just for fun, and this error showed up

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and I'm using Python. And I was making a simple calculator, just to mess around with the IDLE, and I keep getting this error:

```
"ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'bread'"
```

Here is the code I have written.

```
total = float("bread") + float("coffee") + float("milk")
```

I was hoping someone could point me to what is wrong here.

Comment: are you trying to get lenth of the string?

Comment: What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: No, i was trying to make it give the total of the three variables: "bread", "coffee" and "milk". Everything runs fine until the very end, where the total is supposed to show up. Instead of the total, i get an error´.
  ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'bread'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to input the actual variable, not the string of the variable. If you put anything between "", it automatically becomes a [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Try this:

```
total = float(bread) + float(coffee) + float(milk)
```

It will work.

The reason why your program didn't work is, that you can't calculate the float value of a string. Imagine sitting in a maths class and your teacher tells you to calculate what bread plus coffee is.

Because you put the words between "", the compiler interpreted them as strings and not as your variables.